# Can i know which admin user made the changes for order status in admin backend

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, order-status

So basically we have multiple users to manage the admin backend and I wonder if we can  know which user did the changes for the order like for example order status. Is this possible?

Comment: Plenty of admin logger extensions available. If you wanted to build your own, you could fire an observer using `sales_order_save_after` and log the action.